# How to access "onDestroy" when the application is force-killed?

Tags: android

I have an application and I need it to access a code when the app is force-killed. Below I leave the code for better understanding, but it is in onDestroy and does not run when the application is forced to close, just what it wanted!

However, I need the user to get out and back in the application and just when it closes completely it would run this code!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //Ao fechar completamente a tela de validação com o campo textValidacao nulo ou incorreto, o cadastro no autenticacao e no banco de dados sao apagados, para evitar o cadastro de usuarios não validados.
    String codigoDigitado = codigoValidacao.getText().toString(); //Pega o texto da caixa de texto8

    if (! codigoDigitado.equals(tokenGerado)) {//Verifica se esse texto e igual, caso ele seja diferente do tokenGerado

        user = UsuarioFirebase.getUsuarioAtual();//Pega usuario atual

        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { //deleta o usuario no Auth
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {//Testa para ver se funcionou

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Sim");


                }else{

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Não");

                }

            }
        });

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();//Excluir registro no realtime database

        final String identificadorUsuarioLogado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(UsuarioFirebase.getIdentificadorUsuario());//Id usuario

        DatabaseReference usuarioExcluirRef = firebaseRef//Referencia do usuario
                .child("usuarios")
                .child(identificadorUsuarioLogado);

        usuarioExcluirRef.removeValue();//Remove os valores

        DatabaseReference testeOkRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios");//Acessa o no usuarios

        testeOkRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {//testa se o usuario foi deletado, vendo se ainda existe o identificadorUsuarioLogado no nó usuarios
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(identificadorUsuarioLogado)){//Verifica sem tem o filho no nó

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(Banco)","Não");
                    Toast.makeText(ValidadorActivity.this, "Usuario deletado(Banco) - Não", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {

                    Log.i("Usuario deletado(Banco)","Sim");
                    Toast.makeText(ValidadorActivity.this, "Usuario deletado(Banco) - Sim", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    autenticacao.signOut();

    Intent i = new Intent(ValidadorActivity.this, CadastroUsuarioActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. Android can kill your process at any time, without warning.

Comment: Wowww!! yes I am looking for other way to solve my problem

Comment: I do not speak your language, so I cannot determine the intent of your `onDestroy()` function. However, there is usually some way to re-architect your app so that the appropriate information is preserved without unnecessarily confusing your user. (If the Android designers didn't intend for you to be notified of process death, they probably had a good reason for it, and there are more suitable methods of accomplishing your goal.)